# VB.Net Why does my dictionary need to be explicitly declared in order to use select?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Using VB.Net with MVC5.

I have a dictionary:

```
Dim Filter as New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

' the key's value is another dictionary
Filter.Add("customParams", New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"k1","v1"}, {"k2","v2"}, {"k3","v3"}})
```

and I am trying to convert the Filter("customParams") value, which is a Dictionary(Of String, String), to a delimited string, "k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=v3"

This doesn't work:

```
Dim kvString As String = String.Join(", ", Filter("customParams").Select(Function(x) x.Key & "=" + x.Value).ToArray())
```

I get this exception:

> Public member 'Select' on type 'Dictionary(Of String,String)' not
>   found.

But if I explicitly declare a new variable for the Dictionary(Of String,String) and use that instead of Filter("customParams") then **this works:**

```
Dim customParams As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Filter("customParams")
Dim kvString As String = String.Join(", ", customParams.Select(Function(x) x.Key & "=" + x.Value).ToArray())
```

**Why doesn't it work the other way?**  The exception itself says that it's working with a Dictionary(Of String, String)

Comment: `Dim Filter as New Dictionary(Of String, Object) <=` you have an Object here, not a Dictionary. Well, it *contains* a Dictionary, but you're the only one who knows it. Let LINQ know, casting `Object` to `Dictionary` (`DirectCast(Filter("customParams"), Dictionary(Of String, String)).Select(...)`). It'll verify your statement and comply if that's the case. Or declare it for what it is from the start, if possible.

Comment: Why do you declare `Filter` to be `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` when you know it is `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))`? Are other entries in `Filter` going to be of differing types?

Comment: Linq was designed for a language with static type checking.  You really do favor keeping this code in a separate .vb file with Option Strict On at the top.  So the compiler can generate a good error message before it turns into an ugly runtime exception.  Consider the Partial Class keyword to lower the pain of having to keep it separate.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, Filter contains a few other entries of String and Integer type which is why I am using the object type in the declaration.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried enabling Use Strict at the start of this particular project but it has to use a set of legacy libraries (nugets) written by developers long gone and it blows up all over the place.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the explanation.  DirectCast worked as well in place of separately declaring a copy to use.

Comment: That *is* why I recommended keeping it in a separate source file, no need to have it turned on for the entire solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, VB.Net allows *[late binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/index)* (`OPTION STRICT OFF`). Late binding is the equivalent of `dynamic` in C# and means the runtime looks up the method to call by name and the compiler does not type checking or validation. Only *public members* can be accessed by late binding, so extension (friend) methods such as `Select` are not available. This is automatic for `object` variables in VB.Net. `customParams` has a (non-`object`) assigned type and thus uses early binding.